# C to MIPS - Instruction references undefined QTSpim

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I was trying to do an assignment translating from C to MIPS but I get a instruction reference error in jal main. Here is what I have to translate:

```
void swap (int a, int b)
{
   int temp=a;
   a=b;
   b=temp;
}


int distance (int a, int b)
{
   if (b > a) 
      swap (a,b);   

  return (a-b)
}
```

And here is what I wrote:

```
.data       #declare the variables
    var1:   .word 4, 7, 12, 5
    var2:   .word 15, 3, 6, 14
    result: .space 4

.text
main:
    la $t0, var1    #load address 'var1' into $t0
    la $t1, var2    #load address 'var2' into $t1
    la $t2, result  #load address 'result' into $t2

    li $t3, 0       # load imm (i=0)

for_loop:
    bgt $t3, 4, for_done        #when i>4 do not meet condition, exit
    lw $t4, 0($t4)      #result[i] = tmp 
    jal distance
    addi $t3, $t3, 1        #i++
    j for_loop

for_done:
    la $t2, distance
    ori $v0, $0, 4
    syscall


distance:
    blt $t0, $t1, exit
    jal swap
    sub $t5, $t0, $t1
    jr $t5

swap:
    lw $t6, 0($t0)
    lw $t7, 0($t1)

    sw $t6, 0($t1)
    sw $t7, 0($t0)

exit:
```

I actually don't know what am I doing, just the basics of Assembly. I hope some of you could help me. :)

Comment: Even the C code is broken (C is pass by value). Anyway, what's the error and which line? Also, that asm code doesn't resemble the C code at all ... why does it have a loop for example?

Comment: if you want to translate that (broken) C code literally, then just return value `(a-b)`. Must be like ~4-5 instructions at most, all of them probably covered by first 10 examples of any MIPS tutorial (I mean you just need some for how to receive argument, and how to return value, and between you have to find "sub" instruction in the instruction list ... if this makes you go to SO, then I don't want to see your face once you will be asked to actually do some assembly code for real, like some trivial loop... :D ).

Comment: I actually managed to understand how to write it, and it works... You know, it may be hard for someone who have never seen assembly before and want to learn... However, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Mary_CodingGirl it's impossible for somebody who didn't study assembly before to write working code. You have to first study it for few hours/days to get over some initiate knowledge threshold, when it will start to somewhat make sense. Then doing many exercises, watching how they work in debugger and re-reading everything several times again will help. Would that assembly better correlate to your task, and would you describe some particular problem with it precisely, you would get help here for sure, it's just the general tutoring from scratch which SO is not designed for.

Comment: For the title bug: [Getting the error: "Instruction references undefined symbol ... main" in QTSpim](//stackoverflow.com/q/47099284), but Craig's answer very generously covered all / most of the bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but your asm code had [at least] 15 bugs.

I've created two versions: one with the bugs annotated and a second with the bugs fixed and a working program

Note that due to the vagueness of the C code, I had to guess the true intent of the program and take [considerable] poetic license.

---

Here's the unchanged version with the bugs annotated [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data                           # declare the variables
var1:       .word       4, 7, 12, 5
var2:       .word       15, 3, 6, 14

# NOTE/BUG: this only reserves 4 bytes instead of the 16 we need to hold all
# four values
result:     .space      4

    .text

main:
    la      $t0,var1                # load address 'var1' into $t0
    la      $t1,var2                # load address 'var2' into $t1
    la      $t2,result              # load address 'result' into $t2

    li      $t3,0                   # load imm (i=0)

for_loop:
# NOTE/BUG: this goes one too far (i.e. we want i>=4)
    bgt     $t3,4,for_done          # when i>4 do not meet condition, exit

# NOTE/BUG: $t4 is never intialized to anything, so this instruction will fault
# (e.g. equivalent to dererencing a null pointer in C)
    lw      $t4,0($t4)              # result[i] = tmp

    jal     distance

# NOTE/BUG: the index variable 'i' is incremented, but distance does _not_ use
# (i.e.) distance will always use var1[0] and var2[0] on each iteration
    addi    $t3,$t3,1               # i++
    j       for_loop

# NOTE/BUG: what do we want to do here? -- print the result vector presumably
# NOTE/BUG: syscall 4 is to print a string -- it would require setting up $a0
# and _not_ $t2 but, even then, using 'distance' is wrong as distance is the
# function name and _not_ a string so we'd get garbage
# NOTE/BUG: we probably wouldn't even get that far because QtSpim would
# probably fault because distance is in the .text segment and not the .data
# segment
for_done:
    la      $t2,distance
    ori     $v0,$0,4
    syscall

distance:
# NOTE/BUG: this is comparing _addresses_ instead of _values_ (i.e.) this
# compares (&var1[i] > &var2[i]) instead of var1[i] > var2[i])
# NOTE/BUG: this test is _reversed_, because this guarantees negative numbers
    blt     $t0,$t1,exit

# NOTE/BUG: jal is calling swap as a function, but swap is merely a label here
    jal     swap

# NOTE/BUG: based on the mips ABI, return values go into $v0
    sub     $t5,$t0,$t1

# NOTE/BUG: when 'jal distance' is called, the return address goes into $ra
# and to return to the place in main that called us, we want to do 'jr $ra'
# NOTE/BUG: this 'jr' should be at exit:
    jr      $t5

# NOTE/BUG: this actually swaps var1[i] and var2[i] -- would this be correct to
# modify the original arrays???
swap:
    lw      $t6,0($t0)
    lw      $t7,0($t1)

    sw      $t6,0($t1)
    sw      $t7,0($t0)

# NOTE/BUG: this is where the 'jr' should go
exit:
```

---

Here's the cleaned up and working version. I decided that it should store the distance in the result vector and then show all three vectors:

```
    .data
# NOTE: lw/sw must be four byte aligned so keep these first
var1:       .word       4, 7, 12, 5
var2:       .word       15, 3, 6, 14
result:     .space      16

msg_var1:   .asciiz     "var1:"
msg_var2:   .asciiz     "var2:"
msg_result: .asciiz     "dist:"
msg_space:  .asciiz     " "
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

    .text

main:
    la      $s0,var1                # load address of 'var1'
    la      $s1,var2                # load address of 'var2'
    la      $s2,result              # load address of 'result'
    li      $s3,4                   # number of elements in a given vector

    li      $s4,0                   # load imm (i=0)

for_loop:
    bge     $s4,$s3,for_done        # i <= count? if no, fly
    jal     distance
    addi    $s4,$s4,1               # i++
    j       for_loop

for_done:
    la      $a0,msg_var1
    la      $a1,var1
    jal     show

    la      $a0,msg_var2
    la      $a1,var2
    jal     show

    la      $a0,msg_result
    la      $a1,result
    jal     show

    # exit program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# distance -- calculate distance between two numbers in two vectors
#
# RETURNS:
#   stores into 'result' vector
#
# global registers:
#   s0 -- pointer to var1
#   s1 -- pointer to var2
#   s2 -- pointer to result
#   s4 -- array index
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- address and value of var1[i]
#   t1 -- address and value of var2[i]
#   t2 -- temp value
#   t7 -- byte offset corresponding to index 'i'
distance:
    sll     $t7,$s4,2               # convert index to byte offset

    addu    $t0,$s0,$t7             # get &var1[i]
    lw      $t0,0($t0)              # fetch var1[i]

    addu    $t1,$s1,$t7             # get &var2[i]
    lw      $t1,0($t1)              # fetch var2[i]

    bge     $t0,$t1,distance_done   # swap a/b to get abs val? if no, fly

    # swap a/b
    move    $t2,$t0                 # temp = a
    move    $t0,$t1                 # a = b
    move    $t1,$t2                 # b = temp

distance_done:
    sub     $v0,$t0,$t1             # get distance (i.e.) abs(a-b)

    addu    $t2,$s2,$t7             # get &result[i]
    sw      $v0,0($t2)              # result[i] = distance

    jr      $ra                     # return

# show -- show vector
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- vector name
#   a1 -- pointer to vector
#
# registers:
#   t3 -- array remaining count
#
# clobbers:
#   v0
show:
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall to print string
    syscall

    move    $t3,$s3                 # get number of elements in vector

show_loop:
    blez    $t3,show_done           # more to do? if no, fly

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_space           # output a space
    syscall

    # output vector[i]
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall to output value
    lw      $a0,0($a1)              # get vector value
    syscall

    addiu   $a1,$a1,4               # advance pointer to next array element
    addi    $t3,$t3,-1              # bump down count
    j       show_loop

show_done:
    # output newline
    la      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    syscall

    jr      $ra                     # return
```

Comment: Thank you @Craig, it actually helped to know which bugs I had!! I was able to make it work :)